# How to add an array of self-objects to the room database

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, android-room, androidx

I has some data class, which include himself as list.
Android studio shown next error:

```
    ANTLR Tool version 4.5.3 used for code generation does not match the current runtime version 4.7.1ANTLR Runtime version 4.5.3 used for parser compilation does not match the current runtime version 4.7.1ANTLR Tool version 4.5.3 used for code generation does not match the current runtime version 4.7.1ANTLR Runtime version 4.5.3 used for parser compilation does not match the current runtime version 4.7.1C:\..\EventType.java:14: error: Cannot figure out how to save this field into database. You can consider adding a type converter for it.
    private final java.util.List<...EventType> children = null;
Task :app:kaptDebugKotlin FAILED
                                                                                 ^
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:kaptDebugKotlin'.
> A failure occurred while executing org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.internal.KaptExecution
   > java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException (no error message)
```

Data class is

```
@Entity(tableName = "eventType")
data class EventType(
    @PrimaryKey val id: Int,
    val name: String,
    val children: List<EventType>,
    val minAge: Int = 0
)
```

**Edit:** Thanks, next comment was useful
`You have to use teh Room data type converter , look stackoverflow.com/questions/53085704/room-typeconverter – eurosecom`

Comment: You have to use teh Room data type converter , look https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53085704/room-typeconverter

Answer (score 0):

In your `build.graddle` file change:

```
import(Room.compiler)
```

For:

```
kapt(Room.compiler)
```