# Error Room Database: Cannot figure out how to save this field into database. You can consider adding a type converter for it

Tags: database, kotlin

I have a problem when I want to record into Room database my JSON.

My data class is:

```
data class CurrentWeatherEntry(
@SerializedName("temperature")//
val temperature: Int,
@SerializedName("weather_code")
val weatherCode: Int,
@SerializedName("weather_icons")
val weatherIcons: List<String>,
```

)

```
{
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = false)
    var id : Int = CURRENT_WEATHER_ID
}

I get error: Cannot figure out how to save this field into database. You can consider adding a type 
converter for it. 

private final java.util.List<java.lang.String> weatherIcons = null;

How to create converter?
```

Comment: [Duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53085704/room-typeconverter)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Room TypeConverter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53085704/room-typeconverter)

Answer (score 1):

```
object Converter {
   private val gson = Gson()
   private val listTypeConverter = object : TypeToken<List<String>>() {}.type

   @TypeConverter
   @JvmStatic
   fun fromListToIcon(list: List<String>): String = gson.toJson(list, listTypeConverter)

  @TypeConverter
  @JvmStatic
  fun fromIconToList(icon: String): List<String> = gson.fromJson(icon, listTypeConverter)
}
```

Then add `@TypeConverters(Converter::class)` at the top of your DataBase:

```
@TypeConverters(Converter::class)
abstract class YourDB : RoomDatabase()
```