# Kotlin:How to add arraylist into an Entity in data class

Tags: kotlin

I am trying to make a facebook clone app .
And from the very begining ,I will need to define a user class .
And I got stuck here , every users ,supose to have followers list and following list .How do it able to make this model ?
Could you please take a look my code ,thank you so much in advance ！！

```
@Entity(tableName="user_table")
@Parcelize
data class User(
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    val userId : Int=0 ,
    val username :String,
    val email :String,
    val password : String,
    var followers: Array<User>?,
    var followings: Array<User>?,


) : Parcelable

data class UserResponse(val user:User?)
```

Also ,I attach my node.js model schema :

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const router = require("express").Router();

const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    username:{
        type:String,
        required : true,
        min:3,
        max:50,
    },

    email:{
        type:String,
        required:true,
        unique:true
    },
    password:{
        type:String,
        required : true,
    },
    profilePicture:{
        type:String,
        default:''
    },
    coverPicture:{
        type : String,
        default:''
    },
    followers:{
        type:Array,
        default :[]
    },
    followings:{
        type:Array,
        default:[]
    },
    isAdmin:{
        type:Boolean,
        default : false
    }

},
{timestamps:true}
);

const User = mongoose.model('User',userSchema);
exports.userSchema = userSchema;
exports.User = User;
```

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: Hi Robin ,it didn't appear error ,just appears something like warning like ,it needs to generate hashcode  .And after I follow it ,the warning removed .However ,I am not sure if i have writen in the right format,I post it here for asking opinion from you guys  .What do you think ?Any problem my code ? Thank you so much !

Comment: I would use `List<User>?` rather than `Array<User>?` because they are easier to use and I would probably remove the `?` too because the response defaults to an `empty list` and not `null` which is okay in Kotlin so `List<User>` should just suffice

Comment: Probably a good idea would be to separate your network response models from the database entities. Currently the way this is setup, making a change that does not concern the DB will force you to migrate

Comment: Thank you so much for your suggestion Robin !

Comment: What if two users follow each other? This will result in an infinite recursion. To solve this 1) Either put an empty list for followers of followers OR 2) Use a list of userIds to determine followers instead of the entire User model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing you should do is to change

```
var followers: Array<User>?,
var followings: Array<User>?
```

To

```
var followers: Array<Int>?,
var followings: Array<Int>?
```

`Int` may be the type of your userId or make it to `String`
By doing this you will not be recursively fetching your whole database and looping for getting followers and following.

And if you are using `Room` to store your data , add [`TypeConverters`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53085704/room-typeconverter).